# How do the racers differ?

Tags: diddy-kong-racing

Apparently the racers have different characteristics. Do they have different speeds, accelerations, handling etc. or can I choose the racer I want? (tiptup)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[They have different stats it seems](http://www.dkrworld.co.uk/characters.html). Though those look like the N64 version stats (it has banjo). If you're on the DS the stats might be different.

**Edit:** [Here](http://www.mariowiki.com/Diddy_Kong_Racing_DS#Stats) is the stats for the DS version.

**Edit 2:** To more directly answer your question, you can choose whichever you like, but you should be aware of the stats if you'd like to have a better chance of winning. Both links list situations in which each racer does best (and the wiki has a few cons as well).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, their stats are different. You can find information on them easily online, such as this [GameFAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/933008-diddy-kong-racing-ds/faqs/47105). It's for the DS version, but also applies to the N64.

The starting characters are pretty similar. IIRC Tiptup and Timber were the overall best. Sometimes I would use Krunch as his extra speed really helps, especially for boss races.

Special characters are much much better however.

- Drumstick is the best flyer (until Taj/Wizpig in DS).
- T.T. is great on kart and best on hover, although overrated
- Taj/Wizpig is the best flyer (in DS). Many times they are best on kart.

Taj/Wizpig are by far the best if you can control them. Before that (and on N64) use Drumstick and T.T.

Although, it also depends on the track, for instance Taj/Wizpig are terrible on tracks that require precise turns (including bonus minigame tracks).